# How to make a text entry box take up all remaining space left by the button to its right?

Tags: css, html, input, right-align

I'm tempting to resort to tables here since I cannot seem to come up with some CSS that will accomplish what I'm trying to create here.

I have a `<div>` container that contains two things:

- a text entry box (`<input type='text' />`)
- a button (`<input type='button' />`)

I want the button right-aligned (I haven't given it a fixed width, but I easily could). The text entry box should be directly left of the button and take up the remaining space. Here is an example of what I'm looking for:

[image]

Unfortunately, the following HTML isn't accomplishing this (pardon the inline styles - for demonstration purposes only):

```
<input type="button" value="Test" style="float: right;" />
<input type="text" style="display: block; width: 100%;" />
```

I [tried adding a `<div>` wrapper](http://jsfiddle.net/wE7jc/1/), but that didn't work either. What am I doing wrong? I could accomplish this easily with a `<table>` layout, but I'm sure I must be missing something and that there is a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's possible without `<table>`, but it's not very obvious.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/wE7jc/2/

```
<input type="button" value="Test" style="float: right;" />
<div style="overflow: hidden; padding-right: 8px">
    <input type="text" style="width: 100%;" />
</div>
```

The reason this works is explained [here](http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/#making-room-for-floats).

Comment: What's so magical about `'overflow: hidden'`? What does it do and why is it necessary?

Comment: Did you see the (second) link in my answer? I added it a couple of minutes after the initial answer, and it explains nicely why this works.

Comment: If you need the input box to have padding, you will have to add `-[vender]-box-sizing:border-box` or else the input box will be clipped by the `overflow:hidden`.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you don't mind a fixed width button, this should do:

http://jsfiddle.net/4WghJ/

Basically just wrapped the input in a div with a right margin to compensate for the button.